# Undoing a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to animate a menu and have things sliding to the right on `mouseover`. Is there an easy way of undoing everything `mouseover` did when `mouseout`?

I have all the menu items (of my vertical menu) slide to right and have an empty news div slide in place of these menu items, which then gets filled with content, once it is in place... i.e. multiple instances of `animate()`.

Comment: Did you try running the same animation in reverse? Or are your effects more complicated than a single slide?

Comment: Probably. What is it that should be undone?

Comment: You should also use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), I think

Comment: toggle just runs the animation as soon as the page is loaded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like `.stop` function: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

And probably you want to do something like this:

```
$(el).hover(function () {
  $(this).stop().animate(...);
}, function () {
  $(this).stop().animate(...);
});
```

***Example:*** http://jsfiddle.net/VjKLe/

Comment: Sort of. This requires that I set the height explicitly again... For about 15 elements, whose height I only know in em. I was hoping jQuery could have figured all this out automatically...

Comment: Do you mean storing all the information in variables and then recalling this information for the second instance of function()?

Comment: Doing this trick 15 times gives me what I want, I had just thought there might be an easier way already in the jQuery library... Anyway, I wasn't aware of hover and stop, which improved my code considerably. Thanks!